# String property in partial class of the entity framework is not serialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a string property in partial class of the entity framework.

```
public partial class tableTest : EntityObject
{
    public String testA
    {
        get
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("TestB")]
    public List<String> TestB
    {
        get { var list = new List<String>(); list.Add("testB"); return list; }
    }
}
```

Property TestA is not working, but property TestB works.
I tried to add XmlElement, XmlAttribute, DataMemberAttribute... to the TestA, nothing works.

Anyone has a guess?

(.net framework 4.5)

Comment: I doubt that ASP.NET or the entity framework are really relevant. Please come up with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, ideally in as standalone a fashion as possible.

Comment: When talking about serialization, it is a good idea to explicitly state what serializer you are using; it is also a good idea to be very explicit about what "not working" means...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[XmlElement]` suggests you are using `XmlSerializer`; now, if we consider:

```
public String testA
{
    get
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Note that `XmlSerializer` will ignore this because it knows it *can't deserialize it* (there is no setter). A serializer wants to also be able to *deserialize* the data afterwards. It doesn't serialize it because it can't offer deserialization without a setter.

Add a setter. Ideally, for example:

```
[XmlElement("testA")]
public string TestA {get;set;}
```

(and give it the value `"ok"` separately)

Note also that your list won't deserialize properly at the moment either; I would suggest:

```
private readonly List<string> testB = new List<string>();
[XmlElement("TestB")]
public List<string> TestB { get { return testB; } }
```

(and again - add the test data separately)

Answer (score 0):

The deserialiser requires a setter for a serialised property. You must have a public getter and setter for every property that is to be serialised by XML serializer.

Comment: actually, not quite true; lists/collections do not require a setter; it assumes (in that scenario) that the property will be non-null, and that it can just `Add` to the existing collection (etc)